# Gradle: JDBC driver not compiled into JAR

Tags: java, jdbc, gradle

I have a module `build.gradle` file that looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6'
}
```

I also have an artefact set up like this:

[image: Screenshot]

When I build this artifact, my classes are included but MySQL driver is not. When executed, MySQL driver class is not found. How do I build so that my JAR artifact (used as a library)
ccontains MySQL JDBC driver?

Comment: How are you running the application? You need to put the MySQL driver in the class path. Add this line to your dependencies: runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring this in Gradle and IntelliJ is two different things. The most direct way to create a fat Jar in Gradle is:

```
jar {
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.directory ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

PS: Merging Jars can cause problems. In most cases it should not be done, in particular for a library.

Comment: Peter, you are the expert. How about keeping them in separate jars. Will my suggestion work.

Comment: It should definitely be `runtime`, but this won't change anything fundamental. Even with `compile`, the driver will be on the runtime class path.